# How do I chain a Task and Nav.pushUrl in Elm?

Tags: task, elm

In an Elm app I have a Msg handler `LinkedClicked` that returns a `Cmd Msg`:

I want to perform two action for `LinkedClicked`: 1. to update the DOM by updating my Model and 2. reset the page to display from the top by calling `Dom.setViewport`

Is it possible (and desirable) to do away with `ChangeUrl` Msg and instead do `Nav.pushUrl` in my `LinkedClicked` handler. My approach by firing off a Msg within a Msg feels brittle.

```
jump_to_url : Url.Url -> Cmd Msg
jump_to_url url =
    Task.perform ( \_ -> ChangeUrl url) (Dom.setViewport 0 0)


on_birthdate_url : Model -> Url.Url -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
on_birthdate_url model url =
    ( { model
        | ...
      }
    , jump_to_url url
    )


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        LinkedClicked urlRequest ->
            case urlRequest of
                Browser.Internal url ->
                   on_birthdate_url model url
        ...

        ChangeUrl url ->
            ( model
              , Nav.pushUrl model.key (Url.toString url)
            )
```

Comment: Why would it not be possible? Unless the operations actually need to be sequenced you can just use `Cmd.batch` and emit a `NoOp` msg as the documentation suggests.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating the ChangeUrl message and instead do both actions under `on_birthdate_url` to make it clearer that the two actions are strongly related. With batch I suppose I'd create a 3rd message and use batch to indicate that the two message are related to each other. But that's three Msgs and I think 1 Message would be clearer

Comment: `Cmd.batch` combines `Cmd`s, not `Msg`s, so you can still get away with just two, one of them being a `NoOp`. Not entirely ideal, but should make the relationship very clear.

Comment: I tried Cmd.Batch but on Chrome on Android (on desktop Chrome this approach worked) the viewport didn't draw the page at its top. I think because we have no say in when each cmd takes place. So, I've reworked my own code to keep LinkedClicked and ChangeUrl close

Comment: Yes, if it does need to be sequenced, and it sounds like it does, then you do need the separate `ChangeUrl` msg. I think the naming of it could be improved though. Generally I think it's good practice to consider msg's events, not actions, and name them accordingly. Instead of `ChangeUrl` you could name it `ScrolledToTop`. This would also help make the relationship clearer.

Comment: I didn't rename `ChangeUrl` as the code it executes is `Nav.pushUrl`. I deleted `jump_to_url` and `on_birthdate_url` and put `Task.perform ( \_ -> ChangeUrl url) (Dom.setViewport 0 0) )` as the handler for `LinkedClicked/Browser.Internal` - I might put that in its own function as I I felt it needed a comment but I couldn't come up with an elegant name for `Task.perform ( \_ -> ChangeUrl url) (Dom.setViewport 0 0) )` :)

Comment: For completeness: I added a function `new_top_page Url.Url -> Cmd Msg` and this fires off the `ChangeUrl` Msg and `Task.perform` the setting of the viewport. I now have a reusable function that can take an url and display the page from the top

Answer (score 0):

After reading everyone's comments I came to these conclusions:

1. I don't want the refreshing of the page url and the resetting of the viewport to happen concurrently. The former needs to happen before the latter otherwise the viewport reset can happen too early.
2. renaming the function `jump_to_url`  to `new_top_page` encapsulates both the url update and viewport update.

I'm still wondering if encapsulating two actions into one function is the `elm` way.

```
new_top_page : Url.Url -> Cmd Msg
new_top_page url =
    Task.perform ( \_ -> ChangeUrl url) (Dom.setViewport 0 0)


on_birthdate_url : Model -> Url.Url -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
on_birthdate_url model url =
    ( { model
        | ...
      }
    , new_top_page url
    )

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        LinkedClicked urlRequest ->
            case urlRequest of
                Browser.Internal url ->
                   on_birthdate_url model url
        ...

        ChangeUrl url ->
            ( model
              , Nav.pushUrl model.key (Url.toString url)
            )
```